# App crashing on changing views after login

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Good morning!
I am very new to iPhone/iPad programming
My app is crashing (signal SIGABRT) after trying to change views after a Login

```
-(void)checkLogin {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LoginData" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    //Parse lines into an NSArray;
    NSArray *results= [myText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];// Assumes Mac line end return

    if([txtUsername.text isEqualToString: [results objectAtIndex:0]]&& [txtPassword.text isEqualToString: [results objectAtIndex:1]]) 
    {
        Clients * clients = [[Clients alloc] initWithNibName:@"clients" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:clients animated:YES];     
    }

    else 
    {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                        message:@"Wrong credentials"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
    }    
}
@end
```

The app is crashing at this line

```
 [self presentModalViewController:clients animated:YES];
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: what about this; Clients * clients = [[AboutUs alloc]... ? You are declaring a Clients but allocating a AboutUs :)

Comment: Yes, this is where the bug seems to be, maybe you should also post how your "AboutUs" initialization events.

Comment: I was trying the code with the allocation of clients, I edited the question

Comment: are you doing this in the AppDelegate?

Comment: No this code is in a class called "Sign in" Its a view controller

Answer (score 0):

```
Clients * clients = [[AboutUs alloc] initWithNibName:@"clients" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:clients animated:YES];
```

I think the first line is where your app gets stuck. turn it into:

Clients *clients = [[Clients alloc] initWithNibName:@"clients" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:clients animated:YES];

This code should work, but In your question, you put a certain `aboutUs` in your code.

I don't know what you want to do with this from you question, but if you want to put this `AboutUs` controller inside your `Clients` controller, you should use something like:

```
Clients *clients = [[Clients alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUs];
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you! the about us was an error. I edited my code, but still getting the exception. I've been spending more than to hours on this!

Comment: I saw your edited question, try this:[self presentController:clients animated:YES completion: nil]; this always works for me. remember, when you have subclassed AboutUs in Clients, only put Clients in this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like this:

```
Clients *myClients = [[Clients alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:clients animated:YES completion:^(void) {

}];
```

It should work properly. If it still crashes, something in the Clients class is going wrong.